# Split long string into small chunks without breaking HTML tags and words

Tags: javascript, php

I am breaking long text into smaller chunks using while loop. My string contains html code and I dont want the user to see those open or closed braces.

my template string contains following text.

```
var text = "I love Stackoverflow. It helps me lot and Bla bla bla bla bla bla ";

var textString = '<div class="row page col-md-12 "><h4 style="margin-left:20px;"> 
<u> Working from home</u></h4><p style="margin:30px;">'+text+'<p></div>';
```

I am using the following method

```
var i = true;
      var start = 0;
      var end = 20;
      var increment = 0;
        var incremented = 0;
       var val1 = textString.slice(start,end);  
        while (i == true) {                                     
             val1 = data.slice(start,end);
                var check  = val1.endsWith(' ');
            while (check == false) {
            end = end+1;
                incremented = incremented+1;
            val1 = data.slice(start,end);
                if(val1.endsWith(' ')){
                check = false;
                }else{
                check = true;
                }
                 end = end+20+incremented;
                 start = start+20+incremented;
                 if(start>textString.length){
                      i=false;
                 }
         }
}
```

An Example is here:

```
    var text1 = 'I love Stackoverflow. It helps me lot and Bla bla bla bla bla 
    bla';
    var text2 = 'Some Random Text';
    var text3 = 'Some Random Text';
    var text4 = 'Some Random Text';
    var text5 = 'Some Random Text';
    var text6 = 'Some Random Text';

    var textString = '<div class="row page col-md-12 "><h4 style="margin-left:20px;"> 
    <u> text1 </u></h4><p style="margin:30px;">'+text2+'<p></div>
    <div class="row page col-md-12 "><h4 style="margin-left:20px;"> 
    <u> text3</u></h4><p style="margin:30px;">'+text4+'<p></div>
    <div class="row page col-md-12 "><h4 style="margin-left:20px;"> 
    <u>text5</u></h4><p style="margin:30px;">'+text6+'<p></div>';
```

and output i need should be like

```
    arr[0] = ' <div class="row page col-md-12 "><h4 style="margin-left:20px;"> 
    <u> text1</u></h4><p style="margin:30px;">'+text2+'<p></div>';

    arr[1] = '<div class="row page col-md-12 "><h4 style="margin-left:20px;">  
    <u> text3</u></h4><p style="margin:30px;">'+text4+'<p></div>';

    arr[2] = '<div class="row page col-md-12 "><h4 style="margin-left:20px;"> 
    <u> text5</u></h4><p style="margin:30px;">'+text6+'<p></div>';
```

This is my Current output:
[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am creating flipping book using turn.js, i have long text that i want to break into smaller chunks. The Above given string is just an example, i have a string which contain hundred of text lines and some of the text lines are wrapped by <p> with some styles, i want to show it on front end without breaking any English words or any HTML tags,

Comment: What smaller chunks do you mean though? Do you just want the text and HTML tags separated from each other?

Comment: Can you provide the expected output for your example?

Comment: i have long text string of more than 2k words, small chunks means small string of 600 words to be displayed to user on each page of flipping book. these small string may contain HTML tags and i dont want them to get broken. other wise users can see 
`background-color:red;text-align:center'> `

Comment: Can you provide the *literal* expected output for your example?

Comment: I have added picture of my current output, you can see the last word is cut off,

Comment: I am asking for a consistent example of both input and output in JavaScript format (string, HTML). Where the output corresponds to the given input. Can you please provide such an example? I'm not asking for images.

Comment: i have added that to question

Comment: OK, that is really a "happy path" example. What if the limit is reached half-way `text2`?

Comment: we should not include it and truncate before that <p> tag so user wont see HTML codes

Comment: I understand that, but you are keeping it vague. Please explictely show what happens with the HTML in such a case in the first chunk, in the second chunk, etc. Which HTML should close and **re-open** ...etc. Think of italics that should continue in the second chunk, nested HTML, ...etc. Please give the most difficult example you can think of, with nested HTML that gets split up in a deep node.

Answer (score 2):

HTML DOM nodes include their content so you can't split them without breaking them. The following code will convert your string into a DOM tree. Split off all the child nodes and re-combine them without breaking words or HTML based on the length of their text content.

If your data is bad and, for example, has a single paragraph that takes up more than one page, or a long series of letters with no spaces, than it is likely you will need to come up with custom solutions for each type of HTML tag and long series of characters.

Even with this solution you may find that additional effort is need to keep pre tags within your page targets.

This function takes two arguments, your string and the maximum length you would like for the textContent in characters.

```
var shard = function(str, len) {

    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.innerHTML = str;
    var child = el.firstChild;

    var parts = [];
        while(child) { 
          if (child.nodeType == 3) {
            var texts = child.nodeValue.split('')
              .reduce(function(a,b){ 
                 if (b.split(/\s/).length > 1) { 
                    a[a[a.length-1].length > 0 ? a.length: a.length - 1] = b; 
                    a[a.length] = ''
                 } else { 
                    a[a.length - 1] = a[a.length - 1] + b;
                 } return a; },['']);
            for(var idx=0; idx<texts.length; idx++) {
                parts.push(document.createTextNode(texts[idx]));
            }
          } else {
            parts.push(child);
          } 
          child = child.nextSibling; 
        }        

    var textParts = parts.map(function(el) { return el.textContent; });

    
    var partsOut = [''];

    var t = 0;

    for(var idx=0; idx<parts.length; idx++) {

        if ((t + textParts[idx].length) > len) {
          partsOut[partsOut.length] = parts[idx].nodeType == 3 ? 
              parts[idx].nodeValue : parts[idx].outerHTML;
          t = textParts[idx].length;
        } else {
          partsOut[partsOut.length - 1] = partsOut[partsOut.length - 1] + (
             parts[idx].nodeType == 3 ? 
             parts[idx].nodeValue : 
             parts[idx].outerHTML
         );
          t += textParts[idx].length;
        }

        
    }

    return partsOut;

};
```

This is probably not what you want to use in a production environment but it does make an attempt, where possible, to break up HTML into unbroken pieces with a target length of the text content.

Answer (score 0):

you could split the string using spaces

```
let wordsArray = text.split(" ")
```

then reduce is to whatever chunks you want

```
let chunks = Array()
const wordsInChunkCount = 100
let temp = wordsInChunkCount
let str = ''
wordsArray.forEach(item => {
  if (temp > 0) {
    str += ' ' + item
    temp--
  } else {
    chunks.push(str)
    str = ''
    temp = wordsInChunkCount
  }
})
```

after that you will have your chunks in the `chunks` array